# Applandeo / Material-Calendar-View issue where events added to the calendarView does not populates only for January 2020

Tags: android, calendarview

The [Applandeo / Material-Calendar-View](https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View) library is not showing events only for January 2020. The events drawable pops up only when I click any of the date in the January month, not automatically like other months. For all other months the events drawable works perfectly. I have attached a video url regarding the same issue.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bdrP3hw16fCiy3aZsVlKtaLlauQbiMvv

The code snippet used to set the events are as below :

```
private void addCalendarViewEvent(String stringDate, String type) {

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        format.parse(stringDate);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(DateAndTime.getyyyyFromFormattedDate(stringDate),
                DateAndTime.getMMFromFormattedDate(stringDate) - 1,
                DateAndTime.getddFromFormattedDate(stringDate));

        switch (type) {
            case "A":
                eventDayList.add(new EventDay(calendar, R.drawable.red_pill));
                break;
            case "H":
                eventDayList.add(new EventDay(calendar, R.drawable.orange_pill));
                break;
            case "P":
                eventDayList.add(new EventDay(calendar, R.drawable.green_pill));
                break;
        }

        calendarView.setEvents(eventDayList);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i just saw the question and gave you a suggestion for how to improve your question, i don't have any experience with this library

Comment: I created a new project and just implemented this library and used your code for adding events, but everything was fine. I used the kotlin version of the library (`implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.8.0-rc01'`). Could you give us more information? For example the flow of updating calendar view or the device model that you test on that.

Comment: @SamiAzar  am using OnePlus 6T as the testing device. Am using php as webservice to retrieve monthly calendar data. For eg: If I pass january 2020, I get all the dates of january with its type as (A,H,P). According to the status I place the drawable resource one at a time per date.